# I can't load images from Firebase - MeteorJS

Tags: html, firebase, meteor, firebase-storage

I am trying to display the data as follows (doesn't work):

```
{{#each request}}
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail" style="padding:0;border:0px;height:300px;overflow-y:auto">

            <img src="{{URLs[0]}}" alt="">

                <div class="container">
                <h4><a href="#">{{title}}</a>
                    <h4 style="color:red;">{{status}}</h4>
                </h4>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
```

and I get the following error printed in the console:

> Exception from Tracker recompute function: debug.js:41 Error: Can't
>   call non-function:
>   https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/omantourplacesapp.appspot.com/o/TourPlacesImages%2FIMG_0005.JPG?alt=media&token=22ab7965-3b03-4e7f-9798-99617b82dd9b

When I replace the following line:

```
<img src="{{URLs[0]}}" alt="">
```

With:

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/2010-02-19_3000x2000_chicago_skyline.jpg" alt="">
```

It works and I can see the image showing in the browser.

Why Firebase images are not working?

**NOTE:** I am building native IOS application and I could retrieve the same image using the same Firebase URL there.

Comment: I'm not real familiar with meteor, but I'm guessing the problem is that your page doesn't know URLs[0] is a variable. Do you need to put it in brackets? {{URLs[0]}}

Comment: @Notmfb I am actually putting it in bracket, sorry it was typo. My bad. Thank you for helping me noticing it

Answer (score 0):

Don't use brackets use {{URLs.0}}